# How to append Secret/ConfigMap hash prefix properly in Helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to append the hash of my Secret or ConfigMap contents to the name of the resource in order to trigger a rolling update and keep the old version of that resource around in case there is a mistake in the new configuration.

This can almost be achieved using `"helm.sh/resource-policy": keep` on the Secret/ConfigMap but these will never be cleaned up. Is there a way of saying 'keep all but the last two' in Helm or an alternative way of achieving this behaviour?

```
$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.2.1", GitCommit:"fe51cd1e31e6a202cba7dead9552a6d418ded79a", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.10"}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Automatically Roll Deployments](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments)

In order to update resource when Secret or Configmap changes, you can add checksum annotation to your deployment

```
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
```

You can revert to your previous configuration with [helm rollback command](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_rollback/#helm)

**Update:**

A ssuming that your Configmap is generated using `values.yaml` file, you can add a **_helper.tpl** function

```
{{- define "mychart.configmapChecksum" -}}
{{ printf "configmap-%s" (.Values.bar | sha256sum) }}
{{- end }}
```

And use `{{ include "mychart.configmapChecksumed" . }}` both as configmap name and reference in deployment.

**configmap.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "mychart.configmapChecksumed" . }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/resource-policy": keep
data:
  config.properties: |
    foo={{ .Values.bar }}
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
   ...
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
        # to add to the container
        name: {{ include "mychart.configmapChecksumed" . }}
```

Please note that you have to keep `"helm.sh/resource-policy": keep` annotation on Configmap telling helm to not delete the previous versions.

You can not use `{{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}` as a configmap name directly because helm rendering will  fail with

```
error calling include: rendering template has a nested reference name
```

Comment: This can cause downtime - suppose the config map is mounted as a volume, you update it but make a mistake, the deployment rolls and new pods fail, but the configmap is also reloaded in the existing Pods which then crash because of the mistake - your whole Deployment then goes down. Appending the hash and making ConfigMaps immutable is the normal way to prevent this

Comment: This is what I mentioned I was doing in the question? The issue is that the old ConfigMaps are never cleaned up, so etcd is going to grow indefinitely with every update